# Hamiltonian paths in bipartite graphs with 2 sets of "almost" same cardinality

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

Suppose we have two finite disjoint sets $A, B \neq \emptyset$ such that $|A|$ and $|B|$ differ by at most $1$, and let $\Gamma = (A\cup B, E)$ where $E\subseteq \big\{\{a,b\}: a\in A, b\in B\big\}$ be a bipartite graph.

If $\Gamma$ is connected and at most $2$ vertices have degree $1$, does $\Gamma$ have a Hamiltonian path?

(It is easy to see that if $|A|, |B|$ differ by more than 1, $\Gamma$ cannot have a Hamiltonian path.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No:

[image: Counterexample]
The two degree one vertices must be start and end, but they meet.

Answer (score 2):

No. Degree $2$ vertex and its neighbors must be on the hamiltonian path in fixed order and there can be many degree $2$ vertices.

Answer (score 2):

**Counterexample.** Draw a 4-cycle with vertices A, B, C, D and edges AB, BC, CD, DA; draw another 4-cycle with vertices E, F, G, H and edges EF, FG, GH, HE; draw a third 4-cycle with vertices I, J, K, L and edges IJ, JK, KL, LI. Draw another vertex M and edges AM, EM, IM. Draw another vertex N and edges BN and DN.

This is a connected bipartite graph on 14 vertices with 7 vertices on each side, every vertex has degree 2 or 3, and the longest path has 10 vertices.